# $http.get returns html code instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, json

I'm trying to get data from data base using angularjs and c#.
The data is fine until the **Response.Write** in tasks.aspx.cs where i'm getting the json from, but the **console.log($scope.data)** prints an html code.

**Angularjs:**

```
 <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', [])
                .controller('mainController',
                    function ($scope, $http,$timeout) {
                        angular.element(document)
                            .ready(function () {
                                $http.get('../tasks.aspx?tp=getInitData')
                                    .then(
                                        function (d) {
                                            if (d.data == "error" || d.data == "") {
                                                //
                                            } else {
                                                $scope.data = d.data;
                                                console.log($scope.data);
                                            }
                                        },
                                        function (d) {
                                            //
                                        });
                            });

                        $scope.msg = {
                            IsError: false,
                            Text: ""
                        }
<script>
```

**Tasks.aspx.cs:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public partial class Tasks : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["tp"] == null) Response.End();
            var tp = Request["tp"] as string;
            var postData = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic obj = postData == "" ? null : JObject.Parse(postData);
            //int id;
            switch (tp)
            {
                case "ping":
                    Response.Write("ok");
                    break;
                case "getInitData":
                    String s = Utils.GetData();
                    Response.Write(Utils.GetData());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is an error and you are getting an html response of 400 or 401 or 500 (or something). Look at the data and actually read the HTML. Also debug your service.

Comment: What does `console.log(d);` show?

Answer (score 1):

Set contentType as "appliation.json" in response

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Utils.GetData()));
Response.End();
```

Comment: Angular js ($http.get) uses `application/json` header by default.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, I had **Rsponse.redirect** at the bottom of Tasks.aspx.cs which I didn't notice, so everything is OK now.
thank you again.